# Chai y Mocha: Tests dinámicos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, chai, mochajs

Estoy aprendiendo sobre Tests unitarios TDD con Mocha y Chai en mi servidor Express con Firebase. No entiendo cómo realizar aserciones en documentos generados aleatoriamente.

Mi test sería algo así:

```js
describe('DELETE - /api/administracion/tickets/:id', () => {
        it('Debería eliminar un ticket', done => {
            const ticketId = '1234'

            chai.request(server)
                .delete('/api/administracion/tickets/' + ticketId)
                .end((err, response) => {
                    response.should.have.status(200);
                    response.body.should.be.an.instanceOf(Object);
                    response.body.should.have.property('message').eq('El ticket se eliminó correctamente');
                    response.body.should.have.property('data').eq(null);
                    response.body.should.have.property('ok').eq(true);
                    done();
                });
        });
 });
```

El problema es que ese `ticketId` es generado aleatoriamente por Firebase. Lo que se me ocurrió es realizar una llamada a la base de datos desde el propio test y obtener el ID del reciente ticket creado, pero no estoy seguro si esto es una buena práctica en Unit Testing. ¿Qué debería hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Eso es más bien un test de integración, pero si quisieras pensarlo como un test unitario, sería:

```
it('Debiera responder a un DELETE con el schema correcto', done => {
  // comprobar status code 200
  // comprobar schema {"message": "se borró el ticker", "ok":true}
}
```

Y tu controlador hacer esa prueba con un mock. **No estás probando Firebase.** No tiene sentido que si tu controlador está bien tus tests fallen porque Firebase está caído.

En un test de integración, por su parte, lo que quieres probar no es

```
debería poder eliminar un ticket adivinando su id
```

Sino

```
dado el iD de un ticket existente, debería poder borrarlo
```

Para eso puedes crear un ticket usando "before". Ojo, no pruebas la creación y la eliminación juntas. Lo de arriba no debe interpretarse como

```
debería poder crear un ticket y luego borrarlo
```

Sino

```
dado que un ticket se creó y no es problema mio si fue a mano y falló otro test... debería poder borrarlo sabiendo su ID
```